# Display json data as table in view of MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am working in MVC 4 application. i am trying to bind the json data to table in view that reflects as a table view in the View Page.

here is my controller code....

```
if (reportType == "Report")
{
    result = client.GetApiRequest("api/TurnoverReport/get?packageID=" + Convert.ToInt32(packageID)).Result;
}
```

here in result is a datatable that holds the output data as a datatable.
[image: this is the table in result]

to pass the table to View i am serializing the table as :

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            row.Add("text", result);
            rows.Add(row);

var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Formatting.Indented,
                        new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                        });

return Json(serializer.Serialize(test), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

here I'm using the jsonconvert because of i am having this error message like

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.

so, this json return the data as :
[image: the data that is returning the json to View]

i have tried like to display in View but i couldn't get the expected result..
here is the View code that;

```
 function GenerateReport(packageID) {
    var repType = '@ViewBag.ReportType';
    $.ajax({
        url: '/turnover/GetTurnover' + repType,//?packageID=' + packageID,
        data: { "packageID": packageID },
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
```

Comment: what problem are you facing ? are you able to get the response in ajax call ?

Comment: i am getting the data into "response"... now i need to display it as a table here that which i don't know how to.. @FrebinFrancis

Comment: first please put json as text not image

Comment: @htiru http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sewm6/ Please take a look at this

Comment: @FrebinFrancis the table header section is not static rather the fields are generated dynamically.. like these fields may change for another case..

Comment: @htiru so first you need to get the list of columns(Headers) along with the list of records and first render the header columns(<th></th>) before rendering the values(<td></td>) like you see in the JSfiddle.

Comment: can you specify the modifiers of your web method and is the javascript method "GenerateReport" is the one you are using to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one in your javascript method

```
function GenerateReport(packageID) {
    var repType = '@ViewBag.ReportType';
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/turnover/GetTurnover' + repType,//?packageID=' + packageID,
        data: '{"packageID":' + packageID + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //loop to data.text
            $.each(data.text, function( index, row ) {
               console.log(row);
            });
        }
```